# iPhone Objective-C CoreLocation: Want to populate table with data based on current location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

I am trying to get the current longitude and latitude right before the table loads and use the coordinates to make an HTTP request to get a list of nearby locations to display in a table. Right now, I am calling `startUpdatingLocation` in `viewWillLoad`, which is too late. My problem is that I can't seem to get the locations before the table loads, and as a result, the coordinates that are sent in the request are always (0,0).

What would be a better way to approach this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call startUpdatingLocation a delegate is called every few seconds. At this point you could grab the data and then tell your table to reload.

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

In here you would update your data store then you would call [tableView reloadData].